# Android update data fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

It will be like 3 hours I try to update data from a activity to a fragment. I check all pages but it didn't work...

I have to made a BookManager. I have create some class to do it.

I have a main activity with two fragment, a first empty for the moment and a second with the summary of my list of book (most price of book, average...). When I want to add a book, I use a new activity and take data back after add the book (its work).
and I want to refresh the fragment after add the book.

Code of my main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

private SimpleBookManager bookManager;

public final static int ADD_BOOK_REQUEST = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bookManager = new SimpleBookManager();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.button_add_menu) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddBookActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_BOOK_REQUEST);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    if (requestCode == ADD_BOOK_REQUEST) {
        // On vérifie aussi que l'opération s'est bien déroulée
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // On affiche le bouton qui a été choisi
            String[] valueBook = data.getStringArrayExtra("VALUE");

            Book book = this.bookManager.createBook();

            book.setTitle(valueBook[0]);
            book.setAuthor(valueBook[1]);
            book.setCourse(valueBook[2]);
            book.setIsbm(valueBook[3]);
            book.setPrice((int) Integer.parseInt(valueBook[4]));

        }
    }
}


/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            case 1:
                Fragment frag = SummaryFragment.newInstance(bookManager);

                return frag;

        }
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "COLLECTION";
            case 1:
                return "SUMMARY";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the method onActivityResult, I add the book and I want here to refresh or eventuelly when I'm back to the summary fragment. I tried with a `FragmentTransaction`, but the commit didn't work, because I don't have a tag to get my fragment (I don't know how it works to get one)... And the we don't have instance of the fragment because we use a static method to create it.

Code of my fragment :

```
public class SummaryFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String BOOKMANAGER = "book";


    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String[] info;


    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *

     * @return A new instance of fragment SummaryFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static SummaryFragment newInstance(SimpleBookManager bookManager) {

        String[] info = new String[5];

        info[0] = String.valueOf(bookManager.count());
        info[1] = String.valueOf(bookManager.getTotalCost());
        info[2] = String.valueOf(bookManager.getMaxPrice());
        info[3] = String.valueOf(bookManager.getMinPrice());
        info[4] = String.valueOf(bookManager.getMeanPrice());

        SummaryFragment fragment = new SummaryFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putStringArray(BOOKMANAGER, info);

        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    public SummaryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            this.info = getArguments().getStringArray(BOOKMANAGER);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View rootView;
        TextView textView;

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary, container, false);


        textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nbbook_value);
        textView.setText(this.info[0]);

        textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.totalcost_value);
        textView.setText(this.info[1] + " SEK");

        textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mostprice_value);
        textView.setText(this.info[2] + " SEK");

        textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.leastprice_value);
        textView.setText(this.info[3] + " SEK");

        textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.averageprice_value);
        textView.setText(this.info[4] + " SEK");

        return rootView;
    }


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {


        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        Activity a;

        if (context instanceof Activity){
            a=(Activity) context;
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the Fragment instance by calling FragmentPagerAdapter's getItem method.

```
SummaryFragment frag = (SummaryFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
```

And then call a method in the Fragment instance to refresh display, make sure to check null before calling method on the Fragment.

```
if (frag != null) {
        frag.refreshBook(book);
    }
```

Comment: I can get my frag, nice ^^. But how you refresh with the new data inside the fragment. I change value of my private attribut info[], and now I would like to reapply the oncreateview with new data.

I need to do it like this ?

public void refreshBook(SimpleBookManager book)
    {
        String[] info2 = new String[5];

        info2[0] = String.valueOf(book.count());
        info2[1] = String.valueOf(book.getTotalCost());
        info2[2] = String.valueOf(book.getMaxPrice());
        info2[3] = String.valueOf(book.getMinPrice());

        this.info = info2;
    }

Comment: No need to re-create the View of the Fragment again, just find those Views by using findViewById and change the content: for example, TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview); tv.setText(...)

Comment: But we need the inflater to take the root to get them no ?

Comment: You've already got all the TextViews in onCreateView method, just use them.

Comment: I tried, but I got a fatal error :'(. I save textview when the onCreateView, but when I try to use it again in the refresh, it don't work

Comment: Then you will have to save the book instance in the field, and set values in onCreateView if the book field is not null. Once the onCreateView is called again when this Fragment appears, the values will be set.